# Why can't I see my character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the fourth game of The Elder Scrolls (Oblivion) I remember that I could see my own character, but now in Skyrim can't see myself anymore.

Why is that, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same problem but it's not because of the changing of perspectives (pressing the "F" button). It happened after I let someone in the College of Winterhold test her magic on me. Now I can't see my character. I know it's a bug because every time I load the game I see myself for a split second then suddenly I disappear. I'm not invisible or anything because I can still be attacked/detected by characters in the game. It's really just a bug. Help?

Comment: @imitator101 please follow [this link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and ask the community, I really don't know - I didn't even reach the College of Winterhold yet, lol.. :)

Comment: I just want to thank shadow for answering many of mine and the community's questions, keep up the work. Cute baby btw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean you want a third-person view? On PC you can just scroll down or press F to switch into third-person view, and then scroll back up or press F again to switch back. On Xbox or PS3 you can click the right thumbstick in to toggle between first and third person views.

Comment: PC, and I'm pretty sure I pressed F but nothing happened. Is this available from the beginning of the game? Anyway will try again when in front of the game.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes it is it may because your inside sometimes it glitches for me otherwise i would say its because the key has been rebound. try going into settings/controls and finding the camera button and make sure it is assigned to an expected key.

Comment: It's not available from the beginning of the game. It's only available after you finish the movement tutorial.

Comment: ive done all this each one and i still cant complete it but i have it for the ps3

Comment: use the scoll wheel

Answer (score 16):

You can see your character by simply pressing <kbd>F</kbd>: it changes the camera mode to third person/vanity. You can also hold the scroll wheel to rotate around your camera. There is no way to see your character in the menu like in Oblivion though.

Sometimes not being able to go into third person view can be caused by being in a tight area where the camera can't zoom out. Try going into an open area and pressing it a couple of times (sometimes it takes me 2-3 presses to get it to work); if it doesn't work I would say it's assigned to a different key. Go into Settings/Controls and check what key it is assigned to and use that one or reassign it.

Comment: Please note that you need to hold the F key to rotate around the character.

Comment: I roll the mouse wheel back and forth to "scroll" between perspectives :)

Comment: you don't need to hold f as long as you aren't holding your weapons in your hands

Comment: +1 of course and thanks for the detailed explanation, but Jeffrey posted more or less the same before so I'm accepting his answer. When pressing F first time I probably didn't wait long enough to see the change..

Comment: @ShadowWizard xD i was typing the answer as he posted his but its all good glad i could help.